# Django form has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: python

This is the code I have, and when I run it on Django, I am met with this error: 'Title' object has no attribute cleaned_data

```
def new(request):
    
    form = Title(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid:
           title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
           text = form.cleaned_data["text"]
           util.save_entry(title, text)
        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html",{
                "form":NewForm()
            })
        return redirect(reverse('page', args = [title]))
    
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/newpage.html",{
        "form1":Title(),
        "form": NewForm()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the exception thrown in your return statement where you are instantiating a new Title object. This object only gets the cleaned_data attribute when `is_valid` method has been called upon. Hence you haven't called this on the new Title object and that is the reason why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, a similar error is not called for the NewForm() object, which is also a form.

Comment: Answer written by @arifulislam seems to be correct. You need to call the method by writing the paratheses

Comment: Also, my mistake in my answer. You are not accessing the cleaned_data in the return statement, so the error cannot be raised from there.

Answer (score 0):

you use `form = Title(request.POST)`, but the line after you check whether the **request.method** equals **POST** or not. i think yo should move that line inside the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

## is_valid() it's a function

```
def new(request):
    form = Title(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            text = form.cleaned_data["text"]
            util.save_entry(title, text)
       
        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html",{
            "form":NewForm()
        })
    return redirect(reverse('page', args = [title]))

return render(request, "encyclopedia/newpage.html",{
    "form1":Title(),
    "form": NewForm()
})
```